# How to access pocketbase custom hooks values in sveltekit?

Tags: sveltekit, pocketbase

After inserting data into database, I want to get ID of inserted data and use it in frontend (sveltekit).

To get ID, I did this,

```
onRecordAfterCreateRequest((e) => {
    const post_id = e.record.getId;
}, "posts")
```

I don't know how to use this `post_id` in sveltekit.